# Will I be able to read xml from php file?

Tags: php

I have apps that read online settings, and until now these settings are stored in xml. So my app read it's setting straight forward:

```
"http://foo.net/app/setting.xml"
```

But I want it to be easier to maintain, and store a lot of data in the database, So im thinkink of replacing `../app/setting.xml` with something like `../setting.php` where I in the php file would do something like

```
<?php

include mysql stuff ..

$bookid = $_GET['id'];
read database based on $bookid;

?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
<name><?php echo $row['name']; ?></name>
<published><?php echo $row['published']; ?></published>
</book>
```

Is it doable? Do I have to care about header stuff like header expires and cache?

Comment: "Will I be able?" If you keep on learning and trying… But rather than concatenating strings I would use one of the PHP XML lib's to build the document,.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is doable. You can send your XML headers by

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
```

before any output.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/xml");

...
$bookid = $_GET['id'];
...

?>

**here your XML.**
```

Now you can handle it as a normal xml file.